# php mysqli data count and search function not working

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, count

My condition does not work if the result is 1 or 0.
Couldn't understand the problem, could you please help?

```
function habervarmi_update($deger) {
require 'connect.php';
$sonuc=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) from tb_haber  where haber_title='$deger'");
$say=mysqli_fetch_array($sonuc);

if($say>=1){
// kayit var ise var anlamında true gönder
  return true; 
}
else
{
 // kayıt yok ise yok anlamında false gönder
  return false; 
}
}
```

Comment: You use $con in your function, but this variable is not available? You can pass it as parameter in your function 
 habervarmi_update($con, $deger) { ...

Comment: Not sure what your expecting, but `$con` is undefined in this function, `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns the columns in a row from your SQL, so `count()` will be the number of columns and not the number of rows and `$kayit=1` is assigning and not test for equal (which is `$kayit==1`)

Comment: Variables available, only part not working,

Comment: here is what I want to do; if there is a record with the same name, or if there is a zero record, the result is correct,

Answer (score 0):

You are making your variable `$kayit` equal (`=`) to `1` or `0`, instead of comparing it. Comparing is done with the double equal sign operator: `==`.

The statement you mean is this:
`if($kayit==1 || $kayit==0){`

Answer (score 0):

Your function will not work if you don't pass $con to it :

```
function habervarmi_update($deger, $con) { ...
```

Or you can use :

```
global $con; // Which is not recommended
```

Then, you have to compare the variable $kayit with double equal (==), one single equal will add the value (the number in your case) to your variable.

```
if ($kayit == 1 || $kayit == 0) { ...
```

Or even easier :

```
if ($kayit <= 1) { ...
```

Comment: Good :) Don't forget to select the correct answer :)

Comment: Soheyl, I asked a new question at this address, can you see if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009353/php-with-ajax-in-form-input-data-update

Comment: I will check :)